# Visual Studio Bug

Tags: visual-studio

To access the properties of controls in Visual Studio (Windows Form Application), I currently have to follow a multi-step process. Firstly, I need to double-click on the controls in the design page, which then navigates me to the corresponding code page (.cs). However, to view and modify the properties, I have to switch back to the design page.

In the past, a single click on the controls would immediately display their properties. Unfortunately, the current workflow requires the additional steps I described above.

How can I fix this? I am using visual studio 2022.